# Using Raspberry Pi Pico W to inference Azure ML using REST endpoint

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, micropython, azure-deployment, raspberry-pi-pico

I can't get a response when trying to inference an Azure ML model deployment on a Raspberry Pi Pico W. I've successfully gotten responses using Python 3.10, but can't get it to work in MicroPython. Results are empty using `urllib.urequests.urlopen()` and I can't figure out how to use it with a `Request` object like in Python.

I'm trying to replicate the working Python code below using [`urequests`, `urllib.urequests` and `uurequests` MicroPython libraries](https://github.com/pfalcon/pycopy-lib/tree/master/urllib.urequest). Documentation suggests `urllib.urequests` should be enough but I've tried all 3 and haven't had any luck. `try/except` clause at the bottom I'm having trouble with:

```
import urllib.request
import json
import os
import ssl

def allowSelfSignedHttps(allowed):
    # bypass the server certificate verification on client side
    if allowed and not os.environ.get('PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY', '') and getattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context', None):
        ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

allowSelfSignedHttps(True) # this line is needed if you use self-signed certificate in your scoring service.

# Request data goes here
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-advanced-entry-script
data =  {
  "input_data": {
    "columns": [
      "PLAT_PH",
      "PLAT_ORP",
      "PSU1",
      "PSU2",
      "PSU3"
    ],
    "index": [0],
    "data": [[3.0, 600, 4.0, 5.0, 0]]
  }
}

body = str.encode(json.dumps(data))

url = 'my-azure-endpoint-url'
# Replace this with the primary/secondary key or AMLToken for the endpoint
api_key = 'my-api-key'
if not api_key:
    raise Exception("A key should be provided to invoke the endpoint")

# The azureml-model-deployment header will force the request to go to a specific deployment.
# Remove this header to have the request observe the endpoint traffic rules
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization':('Bearer '+ api_key), 'azureml-model-deployment': 'platypus-ph-orp-ps-yn-02-1' }

req = urllib.request.Request(url, body, headers)

try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    result = response.read()
    print(result)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as error:
    print("The request failed with status code: " + str(error.code))

    # Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp, which are useful for debugging the failure
    print(error.info())
    print(error.read().decode("utf8", 'ignore'))
```

My attempt:

```
body = str.encode(json.dumps(data))
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization':('Bearer '+ api_key), 'azureml-model-deployment': 'my-azure-deployment' }

response = urequests.request('POST', url, data=body, headers=headers)
print("response: ", response)
result = response.content
print("result: ", result)
```

It returns empty or times out at `result = response.content` while trying to `raw.read()`. `urequests` library:

```
import usocket

class Response:

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.raw = f
        self.encoding = "utf-8"
        self._cached = None

    def close(self):
        if self.raw:
            self.raw.close()
            self.raw = None
        self._cached = None

    @property
    def content(self):
        if self._cached is None:
            try:
                self._cached = self.raw.read()
            finally:
                self.raw.close()
                self.raw = None
        return self._cached

    @property
    def text(self):
        return str(self.content, self.encoding)

    def json(self):
        import ujson
        return ujson.loads(self.content)


def request(method, url, data=None, json=None, headers={}, stream=None):
    try:
        proto, dummy, host, path = url.split("/", 3)
    except ValueError:
        proto, dummy, host = url.split("/", 2)
        path = ""
    if proto == "http:":
        port = 80
    elif proto == "https:":
        import ussl
        port = 443
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unsupported protocol: " + proto)

    if ":" in host:
        host, port = host.split(":", 1)
        port = int(port)

    ai = usocket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, usocket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ai = ai[0]

    s = usocket.socket(ai[0], ai[1], ai[2])
    try:
        s.connect(ai[-1])
        if proto == "https:":
            s = ussl.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=host)
        s.write(b"%s /%s HTTP/1.0\r\n" % (method, path))
        if not "Host" in headers:
            s.write(b"Host: %s\r\n" % host)
        # Iterate over keys to avoid tuple alloc
        for k in headers:
            s.write(k)
            s.write(b": ")
            s.write(headers[k])
            s.write(b"\r\n")
        if json is not None:
            assert data is None
            import ujson
            data = ujson.dumps(json)
            s.write(b"Content-Type: application/json\r\n")
        if data:
            s.write(b"Content-Length: %d\r\n" % len(data))
        s.write(b"\r\n")
        if data:
            s.write(data)

        l = s.readline()
        #print(l)
        l = l.split(None, 2)
        status = int(l[1])
        reason = ""
        if len(l) > 2:
            reason = l[2].rstrip()
        while True:
            l = s.readline()
            if not l or l == b"\r\n":
                break
            #print(l)
            if l.startswith(b"Transfer-Encoding:"):
                if b"chunked" in l:
                    raise ValueError("Unsupported " + l)
            elif l.startswith(b"Location:") and not 200 <= status <= 299:
                raise NotImplementedError("Redirects not yet supported")
    except OSError:
        s.close()
        raise

    resp = Response(s)
    resp.status_code = status
    resp.reason = reason
    return resp

def head(url, **kw):
    return request("HEAD", url, **kw)

def get(url, **kw):
    return request("GET", url, **kw)

def post(url, **kw):
    return request("POST", url, **kw)

def put(url, **kw):
    return request("PUT", url, **kw)

def patch(url, **kw):
    return request("PATCH", url, **kw)

def delete(url, **kw):
    return request("DELETE", url, **kw)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the `requests` module. You would have to use `pip` to install but its always made my life much easier.

```py
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://google.com'
>>> response = requests.get(url)
>>> dir(response)
['__attrs__', '__bool__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_content', '_content_consumed', '_next', 'apparent_encoding', 'close', 'connection', 'content', 'cookies', 'elapsed', 'encoding', 'headers', 'history', 'is_permanent_redirect', 'is_redirect', 'iter_content', 'iter_lines', 'json', 'links', 'next', 'ok', 'raise_for_status', 'raw', 'reason', 'request', 'status_code', 'text', 'url']
>>> response.status_code
200
>>> response.text
'<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content="Search the world\'s information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you\'re looking for." name="description"><meta content="noodp" name="robots"><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><script nonce="BISplWmXV8CO31gdFGUT1w">(function(){var _g={kEI:\'MnkDZe6WI4uwptQPzcKp-AM\',kEXPI:\'0,793110,572358,206,4804,2316,383,246,5,1129120,1197740,661,380090,16111,28687,22431,1361,12312,17587,4998,17075,38444,887,1985,2891,3926,4423,3405,606,60690,6398,8926,2025,1,16916,2652,4,32894,13064,13659,2980,1457,22559,6678,7596,1,42154,2,16395,342,23024,5679,1021,31121,4569,6258,23418,1252,33064,2,2,1,24626,2006,8155,23350,874,6577,3048,10008,7,1922,9779,36284,6175,20199,20136,14,82,16514,3692,109,2412,5856,3785,15203,253,3606,1516,3030,6110,9706,1804,7734,6072,12026,7265,3132,4292,6561,1634,8840,4654,1493,11712,7915,12742,3,9,5400,3592,5210030,109,2,195,3,263,253,5994348,2803117,3311,141,795,19735,1,1,8782,38,96,4,30,10,11,7,120,12,14,89,110,12,15,2,24,23941455,4044106,1007,13290,2376,39283,3382,1397274,346161,46476,23366633,8163,4636,8408,2880,443,1154,3551,5494,937,241,1966,4369,572,603,769,1034,671,2679,431,300,1597,1,476,2447,1,2372,1,1,2,3,2062,3,1156,487,1252,1549,15,1075,2098,1835,2164,553,686,1,639,540,314,1881,1,499,303,41,1492,2,1007,162,121,1,1376,503,1014,2467,893,886,263,515,102,710,712,277,1753,1204,866,264,111,99,179,61,465,770,2,343,1733,96,3142,199,1787,480,556,2,472,515,9,1456,1,270,733,13,264,1487,148,78,1103,561,96,738,117,57,20,92,449,337,598,1,1,2,3,240,1,146,2,190,603,222,29,1,172,82,135,530,301,1,102,377,49,47,1485,451,3,845,1,1722,237,926,689,4,720,143,3,305,1,477,7,1,8,52,4,510,7,1,8,707,557,4,9,219,1705,725,1,134,201\',kBL:\'aqgJ\',kOPI:89978449};(function(){var a;(null==(a=window.google)?0:a.stvsc)?google.kEI=_g.kEI:window.google=_g;}).call(this);})();(function(){google.sn=\'webhp\';google.kHL=\'en\';})();(function(){\nvar h=this||self;function l(){return void 0!==window.google&&void 0!==window.google.kOPI&&0!==window.google.kOPI?window.google.kOPI:null};var m,n=[];function p(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("eid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b||m}function q(a){for(var b=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("leid")));)a=a.parentNode;return b}function r(a){/^http:/i.test(a)&&"https:"===window.location.protocol&&(google.ml&&google.ml(Error("a"),!1,{src:a,glmm:1}),a="");return a}\nfunction t(a,b,c,d,k){var e="";-1===b.search("&ei=")&&(e="&ei="+p(d),-1===b.search("&lei=")&&(d=q(d))&&(e+="&lei="+d));d="";var g=-1===b.search("&cshid=")&&"slh"!==a,f=[];f.push(["zx",Date.now().toString()]);h._cshid&&g&&f.push(["cshid",h._cshid]);c=c();null!=c&&f.push(["opi",c.toString()]);for(c=0;c<f.length;c++){if(0===c||0<c)d+="&";d+=f[c][0]+"="+f[c][1]}return"/"+(k||"gen_204")+"?atyp=i&ct="+String(a)+"&cad="+(b+e+d)};m=google.kEI;google.getEI=p;google.getLEI=q;google.ml=function(){return null};google.log=function(a,b,c,d,k,e){e=void 0===e?l:e;c||(c=t(a,b,e,d,k));if(c=r(c)){a=new Image;var g=n.length;n[g]=a;a.onerror=a.onload=a.onabort=function(){delete n[g]};a.src=c}};google.logUrl=function(a,b){b=void 0===b?l:b;return t("",a,b)};}).call(this);(function(){google.y={};google.sy=[];google.x=function(a,b){if(a)var c=a.id;else{do c=Math.random();while(google.y[c])}google.y[c]=[a,b];return!1};google.sx=function(a){google.sy.push(a)};google.lm=[];google.plm=function(a){google.lm.push.apply(google.lm,a)};google.lq=[];google.load=function(a,b,c){google.lq.push([[a],b,c])};google.loadAll=function(a,b){google.lq.push([a,b])};google.bx=!1;google.lx=function(){};var d=[];google.fce=function(a,b,c,e){d.push([a,b,c,e])};google.qce=d;}).call(this);google.f={};(function(){\ndocument.documentElement.addEventListener("submit",function(b){var a;if(a=b.target){var c=a.getAttribute("data-submitfalse");a="1"===c||"q"===c&&!a.elements.q.value?!0:!1}else a=!1;a&&(b.preventDefault(),b.stopPropagation())},!0);document.documentElement.addEventListener("click",function(b){var a;a:{for(a=b.target;a&&a!==document.documentElement;a=a.parentElement)if("A"===a.tagName){a="1"===a.getAttribute("data-nohref");break a}a=!1}a&&b.preventDefault()},!0);}).call(this);</script><style>#gbar,#guser{font-size:13px;padding-top:1px !important;}#gbar{height:22px}#guser{padding-bottom:7px !important;text-align:right}.gbh,.gbd{border-top:1px solid #c9d7f1;font-size:1px}.gbh{height:0;position:absolute;top:24px;width:100%}@media all{.gb1{height:22px;margin-right:.5em;vertical-align:top}#gbar{float:left}}a.gb1,a.gb4{text-decoration:underline !important}a.gb1,a.gb4{color:#00c !important}.gbi .gb4{color:#dd8e27 !important}.gbf .gb4{color:#900 !important}\n</style><style>body,td,a,p,.h{font-family:arial,sans-serif}body{margin:0;overflow-y:scroll}#gog{padding:3px 8px 0}td{line-height:.8em}.gac_m td{line-height:17px}form{margin-bottom:20px}.h{color:#1967d2}em{font-weight:bold;font-style:normal}.lst{height:25px;width:496px}.gsfi,.lst{font:18px arial,sans-serif}.gsfs{font:17px arial,sans-serif}.ds{display:inline-box;display:inline-block;margin:3px 0 4px;margin-left:4px}input{font-family:inherit}body{background:#fff;color:#000}a{color:#681da8;text-decoration:none}a:hover,a:active{text-decoration:underline}.fl a{color:#1967d2}a:visited{color:#681da8}.sblc{padding-top:5px}.sblc a{display:block;margin:2px 0;margin-left:13px;font-size:11px}.lsbb{background:#f8f9fa;border:solid 1px;border-color:#dadce0 #70757a #70757a #dadce0;height:30px}.lsbb{display:block}#WqQANb a{display:inline-block;margin:0 12px}.lsb{background:url(/images/nav_logo229.png) 0 -261px repeat-x;color:#000;border:none;cursor:pointer;height:30px;margin:0;outline:0;font:15px arial,sans-serif;vertical-align:top}.lsb:active{background:#dadce0}.lst:focus{outline:none}</style><script nonce="BISplWmXV8CO31gdFGUT1w">(function(){window.google.erd={jsr:1,bv:1866,de:true};\nvar l=this||self;var m,n=null!=(m=l.mei)?m:1,p,q=null!=(p=l.sdo)?p:!0,r=0,t,u=google.erd,v=u.jsr;google.ml=function(a,b,d,h,e){e=void 0===e?2:e;b&&(t=a&&a.message);if(google.dl)return google.dl(a,e,d),null;if(0>v){window.console&&console.error(a,d);if(-2===v)throw a;b=!1}else b=!a||!a.message||"Error loading script"===a.message||r>=n&&!h?!1:!0;if(!b)return null;r++;d=d||{};b=encodeURIComponent;var c="/gen_204?atyp=i&ei="+b(google.kEI);google.kEXPI&&(c+="&jexpid="+b(google.kEXPI));c+="&srcpg="+b(google.sn)+"&jsr="+b(u.jsr)+"&bver="+b(u.bv);var f=a.lineNumber;void 0!==f&&(c+="&line="+f);var g=\na.fileName;g&&(0<g.indexOf("-extension:/")&&(e=3),c+="&script="+b(g),f&&g===window.location.href&&(f=document.documentElement.outerHTML.split("\\n")[f],c+="&cad="+b(f?f.substring(0,300):"No script found.")));c+="&cad=ple_"+google.ple+".aple_"+google.aple;google.ple&&1===google.ple&&(e=2);c+="&jsel="+e;for(var k in d)c+="&",c+=b(k),c+="=",c+=b(d[k]);c=c+"&emsg="+b(a.name+": "+a.message);c=c+"&jsst="+b(a.stack||"N/A");12288<=c.length&&(c=c.substr(0,12288));a=c;h||google.log(0,"",a);return a};window.onerror=function(a,b,d,h,e){if(t!==a){a=e instanceof Error?e:Error(a);void 0===d||"lineNumber"in a||(a.lineNumber=d);void 0===b||"fileName"in a||(a.fileName=b);b=void 0;if(a.stack&&(-1!==a.stack.indexOf("?xjs=s0")||-1!==a.stack.indexOf("&xjs=s0"))){b=document.querySelectorAll("script[src*=\\\\/xjs\\\\/_\\\\/js\\\\/]");for(h=d=0;h<b.length;h++)d+=b[h].async?1:0;var c=e=h=-1,f=-1,g=-1;if(performance&&google.xjsu){h=0;e=google.timers.load.t.xjsee?1:0;f=c=0;g=performance.getEntriesByType("resource");for(var k=\n0;k<g.length;k++)-1!==g[k].name.indexOf(google.xjsu)&&(h=1),-1!==g[k].name.indexOf("/xjs/_/js/")&&(c+=1,f+="script"===g[k].initiatorType?1:0);g=c-f}b={cad:"pl_"+h+".pe_"+e+".asc_"+d+".tsc_"+b.length+".fasc_"+(b.length-d)+".lxc_"+c+".lsx_"+f+".lnsx_"+g}}google.ml(a,!1,b,!1,"SyntaxError"===a.name||"SyntaxError"===a.message.substring(0,11)||-1!==a.message.indexOf("Script error")?3:0)}t=null;q&&r>=n&&(window.onerror=null)};})();</script></head><body bgcolor="#fff"><script nonce="BISplWmXV8CO31gdFGUT1w">(function(){var src=\'/images/nav_logo229.png\';var iesg=false;document.body.onload = function(){window.n && window.n();if (document.images){new Image().src=src;}\nif (!iesg){document.f&&document.f.q.focus();document.gbqf&&document.gbqf.q.focus();}\n}\n})();</script><div id="mngb"><div id=gbar><nobr><b class=gb1>Search</b> <a class=gb1 href="https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi">Images</a> <a class=gb1 href="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl">Maps</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8">Play</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://www.youtube.com/?tab=w1">YouTube</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://news.google.com/?tab=wn">News</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm">Gmail</a> <a class=gb1 href="https://drive.google.com/?tab=wo">Drive</a> <a class=gb1 style="text-decoration:none" href="https://www.google.com/intl/en/about/products?tab=wh"><u>More</u> &raquo;</a></nobr></div><div id=guser width=100%><nobr><span id=gbn class=gbi></span><span id=gbf class=gbf></span><span id=gbe></span><a href="http://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=en" class=gb4>Web History</a> | <a  href="/preferences?hl=en" class=gb4>Settings</a> | <a target=_top id=gb_70 href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=http://www.google.com/&ec=GAZAAQ" class=gb4>Sign in</a></nobr></div><div class=gbh style=left:0></div><div class=gbh style=right:0></div></div><center><br clear="all" id="lgpd"><div id="lga"><img alt="Google" height="92" src="/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_white_background_color_272x92dp.png" style="padding:28px 0 14px" width="272" id="hplogo"><br><br></div><form action="/search" name="f"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr valign="top"><td width="25%">&nbsp;</td><td align="center" nowrap=""><input name="ie" value="ISO-8859-1" type="hidden"><input value="en" name="hl" type="hidden"><input name="source" type="hidden" value="hp"><input name="biw" type="hidden"><input name="bih" type="hidden"><div class="ds" style="height:32px;margin:4px 0"><input class="lst" style="margin:0;padding:5px 8px 0 6px;vertical-align:top;color:#000" autocomplete="off" value="" title="Google Search" maxlength="2048" name="q" size="57"></div><br style="line-height:0"><span class="ds"><span class="lsbb"><input class="lsb" value="Google Search" name="btnG" type="submit"></span></span><span class="ds"><span class="lsbb"><input class="lsb" id="tsuid_1" value="I\'m Feeling Lucky" name="btnI" type="submit"><script nonce="BISplWmXV8CO31gdFGUT1w">(function(){var id=\'tsuid_1\';document.getElementById(id).onclick = function(){if (this.form.q.value){this.checked = 1;if (this.form.iflsig)this.form.iflsig.disabled = false;}\nelse top.location=\'/doodles/\';};})();</script><input value="AO6bgOgAAAAAZQOHQsr9t-F6-rohy2SUmWluhf3mvBya" name="iflsig" type="hidden"></span></span></td><td class="fl sblc" align="left" nowrap="" width="25%"><a href="/advanced_search?hl=en&amp;authuser=0">Advanced search</a></td></tr></table><input id="gbv" name="gbv" type="hidden" value="1"><script nonce="BISplWmXV8CO31gdFGUT1w">(function(){var a,b="1";if(document&&document.getElementById)if("undefined"!=typeof XMLHttpRequest)b="2";else if("undefined"!=typeof ActiveXObject){var c,d,e=["MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP","Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];for(c=0;d=e[c++];)try{new ActiveXObject(d),b="2"}catch(h){}}a=b;if("2"==a&&-1==location.search.indexOf("&gbv=2")){var f=google.gbvu,g=document.getElementById("gbv");g&&(g.value=a);f&&window.setTimeout(function(){location.href=f},0)};}).call(this);</script></form><div id="gac_scont"></div><div style="font-size:83%;min-height:3.5em"><br></div><span id="footer"><div style="font-size:10pt"><div style="margin:19px auto;text-align:center" id="WqQANb"><a href="/intl/en/ads/">Advertising</a><a href="/services/">Business Solutions</a><a href="/intl/en/about.html">About Google</a></div></div><p style="font-size:8pt;color:#70757a">&copy; 2023 - <a href="/intl/en/policies/privacy/">Privacy</a> - <a href="/intl/en/policies/terms/">Terms</a></p></span></center><script nonce="BISplWmXV8CO31gdFGUT1w">(function(){window.google.cdo={height:757,width:1440};(function(){var a=window.innerWidth,b=window.innerHeight;if(!a||!b){var c=window.document,d="CSS1Compat"==c.compatMode?c.documentElement:c.body;a=d.clientWidth;b=d.clientHeight}\nif(a&&b&&(a!=google.cdo.width||b!=google.cdo.height)){var e=google,f=e.log,g="/client_204?&atyp=i&biw="+a+"&bih="+b+"&ei="+google.kEI,h="",k=[],l=void 0!==window.google&&void 0!==window.google.kOPI&&0!==window.google.kOPI?window.google.kOPI:null;null!=l&&k.push(["opi",l.toString()]);for(var m=0;m<k.length;m++){if(0===m||0<m)h+="&";h+=k[m][0]+"="+k[m][1]}f.call(e,"","",g+h)};}).call(this);})();</script> <script nonce="BISplWmXV8CO31gdFGUT1w">(function(){google.xjs={ck:\'xjs.hp.Jf8KR87pnmI.L.X.O\',cs:\'ACT90oFT9fKJBn_a_wvD2_Sw2SSO-2z9kw\',cssopt:false,csss:\'ACT90oFGDogp2mJjs6L7kGpzvml1haY4tw\',excm:[],sepcss:false};})();</script>     <script nonce="BISplWmXV8CO31gdFGUT1w">(function(){var u=\'/xjs/_/js/k\\x3dxjs.hp.en.u7mGEg9vNpQ.O/am\\x3dAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAUABAQAAAAAAAAkAAAdAQAwAIAXA/d\\x3d1/ed\\x3d1/rs\\x3dACT90oGP6JIdzMyvm5W6kbICuV5vcQEpJA/m\\x3dsb_he,d,cEt90b,SNUn3,qddgKe,sTsDMc,dtl0hd,eHDfl\';var amd=0;\nvar e=this||self,f=function(a){return a};var g;var h=function(a){this.g=a};h.prototype.toString=function(){return this.g+""};var k={};var l=function(){var a=document;var b="SCRIPT";"application/xhtml+xml"===a.contentType&&(b=b.toLowerCase());return a.createElement(b)};\nfunction m(a,b){a.src=b instanceof h&&b.constructor===h?b.g:"type_error:TrustedResourceUrl";var c,d;(c=(b=null==(d=(c=(a.ownerDocument&&a.ownerDocument.defaultView||window).document).querySelector)?void 0:d.call(c,"script[nonce]"))?b.nonce||b.getAttribute("nonce")||"":"")&&a.setAttribute("nonce",c)};function n(a){a=null===a?"null":void 0===a?"undefined":a;if(void 0===g){var b=null;var c=e.trustedTypes;if(c&&c.createPolicy){try{b=c.createPolicy("goog#html",{createHTML:f,createScript:f,createScriptURL:f})}catch(d){e.console&&e.console.error(d.message)}g=b}else g=b}a=(b=g)?b.createScriptURL(a):a;return new h(a,k)};void 0===google.ps&&(google.ps=[]);function p(){var a=u,b=function(){};google.lx=google.stvsc?b:function(){q(a);google.lx=b};google.bx||google.lx()}function r(a,b){b&&m(a,n(b));var c=a.onload;a.onload=function(d){c&&c(d);google.ps=google.ps.filter(function(t){return a!==t})};google.ps.push(a);document.body.appendChild(a)}google.as=r;function q(a){google.timers&&google.timers.load&&google.tick&&google.tick("load","xjsls");var b=l();b.onerror=function(){google.ple=1};b.onload=function(){google.ple=0};google.xjsus=void 0;r(b,a);google.aple=-1;google.psa=!0};google.xjsu=u;e._F_jsUrl=u;setTimeout(function(){0<amd?google.caft(function(){return p()},amd):p()},0);})();window._ = window._ || {};window._DumpException = _._DumpException = function(e){throw e;};window._s = window._s || {};_s._DumpException = _._DumpException;window._qs = window._qs || {};_qs._DumpException = _._DumpException;(function(){window._F_toggles=[1,0,0,8,1310721,16448,0,9216,1140,24117259];})();function _F_installCss(c){}\n(function(){google.jl={blt:\'none\',chnk:0,dw:false,dwu:true,emtn:0,end:0,ico:false,ikb:0,ine:false,injs:\'none\',injt:0,injth:0,injv2:false,lls:\'default\',pdt:0,rep:0,snet:true,strt:0,ubm:false,uwp:true};})();(function(){var pmc=\'{\\x22d\\x22:{},\\x22sb_he\\x22:{\\x22agen\\x22:true,\\x22cgen\\x22:true,\\x22client\\x22:\\x22heirloom-hp\\x22,\\x22dh\\x22:true,\\x22ds\\x22:\\x22\\x22,\\x22fl\\x22:true,\\x22host\\x22:\\x22google.com\\x22,\\x22jsonp\\x22:true,\\x22msgs\\x22:{\\x22cibl\\x22:\\x22Clear Search\\x22,\\x22dym\\x22:\\x22Did you mean:\\x22,\\x22lcky\\x22:\\x22I\\\\u0026#39;m Feeling Lucky\\x22,\\x22lml\\x22:\\x22Learn more\\x22,\\x22psrc\\x22:\\x22This search was removed from your \\\\u003Ca href\\x3d\\\\\\x22/history\\\\\\x22\\\\u003EWeb History\\\\u003C/a\\\\u003E\\x22,\\x22psrl\\x22:\\x22Remove\\x22,\\x22sbit\\x22:\\x22Search by image\\x22,\\x22srch\\x22:\\x22Google Search\\x22},\\x22ovr\\x22:{},\\x22pq\\x22:\\x22\\x22,\\x22rfs\\x22:[],\\x22sbas\\x22:\\x220 3px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08)\\x22,\\x22stok\\x22:\\x22d-jkpGwmn8md3Y8uNtfF3jq-axc\\x22}}\';google.pmc=JSON.parse(pmc);})();(function(){var b=function(a){var c=0;return function(){return c<a.length?{done:!1,value:a[c++]}:{done:!0}}};\nvar e=this||self;var g,h;a:{for(var k=["CLOSURE_FLAGS"],l=e,n=0;n<k.length;n++)if(l=l[k[n]],null==l){h=null;break a}h=l}var p=h&&h[610401301];g=null!=p?p:!1;var q,r=e.navigator;q=r?r.userAgentData||null:null;function t(a){return g?q?q.brands.some(function(c){return(c=c.brand)&&-1!=c.indexOf(a)}):!1:!1}function u(a){var c;a:{if(c=e.navigator)if(c=c.userAgent)break a;c=""}return-1!=c.indexOf(a)};function v(){return g?!!q&&0<q.brands.length:!1}function w(){return u("Safari")&&!(x()||(v()?0:u("Coast"))||(v()?0:u("Opera"))||(v()?0:u("Edge"))||(v()?t("Microsoft Edge"):u("Edg/"))||(v()?t("Opera"):u("OPR"))||u("Firefox")||u("FxiOS")||u("Silk")||u("Android"))}function x(){return v()?t("Chromium"):(u("Chrome")||u("CriOS"))&&!(v()?0:u("Edge"))||u("Silk")}function y(){return u("Android")&&!(x()||u("Firefox")||u("FxiOS")||(v()?0:u("Opera"))||u("Silk"))};var z=v()?!1:u("Trident")||u("MSIE");y();x();w();var A=!z&&!w(),D=function(a){if(/-[a-z]/.test("ved"))return null;if(A&&a.dataset){if(y()&&!("ved"in a.dataset))return null;a=a.dataset.ved;return void 0===a?null:a}return a.getAttribute("data-"+"ved".replace(/([A-Z])/g,"-$1").toLowerCase())};var E=[],F=null;function G(a){a=a.target;var c=performance.now(),f=[],H=f.concat,d=E;if(!(d instanceof Array)){var m="undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.iterator&&d[Symbol.iterator];if(m)d=m.call(d);else if("number"==typeof d.length)d={next:b(d)};else throw Error("a`"+String(d));for(var B=[];!(m=d.next()).done;)B.push(m.value);d=B}E=H.call(f,d,[c]);if(a&&a instanceof HTMLElement)if(a===F){if(c=4<=E.length)c=5>(E[E.length-1]-E[E.length-4])/1E3;if(c){c=google.getEI(a);a.hasAttribute("data-ved")?f=a?D(a)||"":"":f=(f=\na.closest("[data-ved]"))?D(f)||"":"";f=f||"";if(a.hasAttribute("jsname"))a=a.getAttribute("jsname");else{var C;a=null==(C=a.closest("[jsname]"))?void 0:C.getAttribute("jsname")}google.log("rcm","&ei="+c+"&ved="+f+"&jsname="+(a||""))}}else F=a,E=[c]}window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){document.body.addEventListener("click",G)});}).call(this);</script></body></html>'
>>>
```